# Applying attr to an iframe

Tags: jquery, vimeo, attr, vimeo-api, autoplay

I'm trying to apply attr `allow="autoplay;` to my iframe shown in this image.

[image]

I've tried

```
jQuery(".esg-entry-media-wrapper iframe").attr("allow", "autoplay;");
```

But it's not working.

EDIT : Works with the code below.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     jQuery(".esg-vimeo-frame").attr('allow', 'autoplay');  

    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your iframe doesn't have `.esg-entry-media-wrapper` class
what you should do is give right class.

`jQuery(".esg-vimeo-frame").attr("allow", "autoplay;");`

Edit:

- Maybe you should wait until the `DOM` is ready and then assign that attribute to an element

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it's still not working. Could you please check again?

Comment: if you do that in console `jQuery(".esg-vimeo-frame")` what response do you get? Maybe you should wait until the DOM is ready and then assign that attribute to an element

Comment: that's it. Thanks for your idea.